# How to resize UIlabel inside UIView proportionally?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uilabel

I have a UILabel inside a UIView and I want the label to be resized proportionally as the UIView is resize. 
I was able to do so with a UIImageView but the label stays as big as I placed it in IB.

I have set the view contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit thinking that anything inside the UIView would be "aspect fit" but I had to set the same mode to the UIImageView (which works fine) and I can't set that mode to the UILabel.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it the label you want to resize or the text displayed in the label ?

Comment: Well... I want the label to have the same proportional size inside the UIView... so the text would go bigger and tinier as the view size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears CGAffineTransform is the answer.

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

This would resize the view and everything that is inside dividing the view width and height by 2.

Comment: This makes the text look blurry

Answer (score 0):

set `setAutoresizingMask` of label